Langlands quotient is compatible with contragredient
While studying the Langlands classification following the book of Knapp and Wallach, I had a natural question, namely the compatibility of taking Langlands quotient and contragredient.
Let me just write down the precise meaning in the simplest setting. Say $G$ is a real semisimple Lie group, and $P_0=M_0A_0 N_0$ the Langlands decomposition of a minimal parabolic subgroup. Then we can take a tempered representation $\pi_0$ of $M_0$ and a character $\chi_0$ of $A_0$ in "positive position", and construct the Langlands quotient $J(\pi_0\otimes \chi_0)$, which is the unique quotient of the (normalized) parabolic induction $I_{P_0}^G(\pi_0\otimes \chi_0)$.
My question is that if we take the contragredient $\tilde{\pi}_0$ and $\chi_0^{-1}$ of $\pi_0$ and $\chi_0$, then is $J(\tilde{\pi}_0\otimes\chi_0^{-1})$ the contragredient of $J(\pi_0\otimes \chi_0)$?
I think this must be the case, but I have not yet affirmed this in the textbooks. (It seems that there is not such a proposition in both books.) The Langlands quotient can be obtained by taking the image of the standard intertwining operator, but I do not find this to be helpful to my question.
Can any veteran give me some help? Thanks a lot in advance!
